# ASP.NET Server-Side Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Somewhere in a recent podcast I heard mention of a project where ASP.NET (maybe MVC?) did some sort of behind-the-scenes automatic JavaScript conversion with AJAX to tie the client and server-side code together in a manner similar to the Google Web Toolkit. I've forgotten the name. But it seemed like it was writing C# code that would be converted to either javascript or AJAX calls as needed automatically. It might have been an MS research project.

Does anyone know the name of this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be [ScriptSharp](http://scriptsharp.com/).

Updated new link.

Comment: Thanks! OMG I was pulling my hair out looking for it.